# calling fork() in a for loop

Tags: c, fork

Please help, this is a possible interview question I'm going to face tomarrow:

find the output of

```
main()
{
 int tmp;
 for(i=0;i<9;i++)
 {
  tmp=fork();
  if(tmp>0)
  break;
  printf(“Hello”);
 }
}
```

Comment: And what exactly is your question ?

Comment: the output of above program ?

Comment: This is not a good question for this website; the output of that program can be verified by anybody.

Comment: Sorry I meant o/p with explaination

Comment: This is an interesting question. Just looking at the code, I would say 9 because all the fork()s that return a pid break from the loop. So only those returning 0 would print. That would be 9. But the actual output is different, and the output changes if you add a "\n" to the Hello string. So, my original answer below is bogus.

Comment: After playing with it a bit, I think the count does depend on scheduling.

Comment: They share "i" right? So all bets are off?

Comment: 9 + 8 + 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 45.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is that fork() will return a different value to the original process than it does to the new, child process.  In particular, it returns 0 to the child, and the pid of the child to the original. From that, you can figure out the output.

(Well, you could if used puts() instead of printf(), but since you're not terminating the lines, that makes the output somewhat non-deterministic, as @CharlieBurns pointed out.)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0;i<9;i++)
 {
  tmp=fork();
  if(tmp>0)   // if parent 
      break;
  printf(“Hello”);
  fflush(stdout);   // if add this , I know the output:
 }
```

This means :

each parent process fork a new process and break , then exit;

each child process print "Hello" and fork it's child process .

```
         i=0           i=1                            i = 8
        fork          fork                            fork
process 0 --> process 1 --> process 2 ... ->process 8 -->  process9
     |         |      |        |    |        |      |       |
     |       "Hello"  |     "Hello" |       Hello"  |    "Hello"
    break          break          break            break
```

Total 9 "Hello" printed.

Without flush the buffer , Nobody knows the correct output. Bacause fork also copy the buffer from parent to child .

Comment: The logic of the calls is correct, and while it is true that printf will be called 9 times, many more Hellos will appear -- try it!

Comment: @ScottHunter Yes , you are right, forgot the buffer thing